# Using Visual Studio Maui Android the compilation error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point is nonsense

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, maui

The Android platform part of a visual studio maui program does not need a Main entry point. How can this be specified to visaul studio ?

I tried changing properties, but found none that allowed visual studion to recognize it did not need a Main entry point .

Comment: What version of VS? What dotnet version? What template did you use to create the project (if any)? Do you have the appropriate workloads installed for maui development? => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/installation?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vswin

Comment: You can try to delete the bin folders and the obj folders and rebuild it.  If it doesn’t work ,try to restart the VS.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, try to [repair your visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).

Comment: I am using VS 2022 version 17.5 and dotnet 7.0.300-preview.23122.5 and all the appropriate workloads have been newly installed. Even a VS repair doesnot solve the problem . I have also deleted the bin and obj folders with no success .

Answer (score 0):

do not remove MacCatalyst directory from Platforms

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).